# Where to download n900 songbird client?

Tags: songbird, nokia-n-series

I am confused ... is Songbird releasing a client for the n900?  This page has been up for a few months.  I've been eagerly awaiting a download, but cannot find the link:

http://getsongbird.com/gadgets/

Does anyone have any ideas here?

The media player with the n900 works well, but it doesn't connect to last.fm.  It isn't a deal breaker, but it would be a nice to have.  Songbird seems to run better than Rhythmbox and offers a cleaner, more polished look.

Thanks,
Walter

Comment: you mean an app that runs on the n900?  i think that page just shows devices that the Songbird PC application can sync to.  i don't know for sure tho.  (if you *are* looking for an app for your phone, this question will be closed; smartphone apps are offtopic on this site.)

Comment: that's unfortunate.  I'd really like to have transparent integration with all of those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page signifies the device to which Songbird can sync with.  Meaning if you want to sync your music tracks between your laptop and your N900.

Songbird is not a mobile application, it's a desktop application which runs on Windows/Mac/Linux.

I'd suggest you install Songbird on your computer, then use Songbird to administer your music collection on your phone.  Songbird is a great application.

Comment: Thanks I figured as much, but was hoping for more.

Comment: Totally, well there are some interesting things being done with the Banshee music player.  Integrating it into an overall interface, this might be a stepping stone to putting apps like Banshee and Songbird on Tablets, and smart phones.

Comment: Here's the link;

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/May-27.html